# KVM Pass through disk Partition - By Label or UUID

Tags: kvm-virtualization, diskmanagement, passthrough

Normally, when I passthrough a disk to a VM I use the entire disk. **I am looking at attempting to passthrough a *partition* in KVM**. First question is that possible/ok? Looking at this doc it seems to be the way to go which supprised me.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_administration_guide/sect-virtualization-adding_storage_devices_to_guests-adding_hard_drives_and_other_block_devices_to_a_guest

> Important
>
> **Guest virtual machines should not be given write access to whole disks or block devices (for example, /dev/sdb).** Guest virtual
>   machines with access to whole block devices may be able to modify
>   volume labels, which can be used to compromise the host physical
>   machine system. **Use partitions (for example, /dev/sdb1) or LVM
>   volumes to prevent this issue.**

My next question is I have read about how to do this via /dev/sdX and by diskID, but DiskID seems to be the entire disk, IE:

https://lime-technology.com/forums/topic/34659-hard-drive-passthrough/

```
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
        <source dev='/dev/disk/by-id/ata-Corsair_CSSD-F120GB2_1109650632000461003B' />
        <target dev='hdc' bus='virtio' />
</disk>
```

And the whole point of using the by-id is because /sdX can change. **I was wondering if I can use LABEL or UUID?** Anybody with experience, I'd like some input.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can passthrough a disk via any of the following symlinks in /dev/disk/by-* eg:

```
cd /dev/disk/by-
by-id/        by-label/     by-partlabel/ by-partuuid/  by-path/      by-uuid/
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look carefully at the disk symlinks in `/dev/disk/by-id` you will see that there are also links for each partition on the block devices. For instance:

```
ata-INTEL_SSDSC2BB480G7_PHDV644200N5480BGN
ata-INTEL_SSDSC2BB480G7_PHDV644200N5480BGN-part1
ata-INTEL_SSDSC2BB480G7_PHDV644200N5480BGN-part2
ata-INTEL_SSDSC2BB480G7_PHDV644200N5480BGN-part3
ata-INTEL_SSDSC2BB480G7_PHDV644200N5480BGN-part5
ata-INTEL_SSDSC2BB480G7_PHDV644200N5480BGN-part6
ata-INTEL_SSDSC2BB480G7_PHDV644200N5480BGN-part7
```

Use the one corresponding to your desired partition.

Comment: I'm literally about to do some partitioning, so I can't set this up until after I do that, but if I could do it by LABEL or UUID, I could just set it up now and change the other partitions later

Comment: The partition number will always be the same unless you repartition the block device.

Comment: Thats the plan, I'm about to delete part-3 and grow part-2, but I want to passthrough lets say "part-5", im worried if I do any changes in the future,"part-5" could become "part-4", but its UUID wouldn't change.

Comment: Just to confirm though, it is OK to just pass through a Partition vs entire disk?

Comment: Yes, you can pass through a partition. Whether you rearrange their numbers or not, is up to you.

Comment: turns out you can do by-uuid or by-label! @Michael Hampton, I was tab completing when I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the symlink in either ID or By Label path and then using that for the partition:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id
ls -l /dev/disk/by-label

#After getting the id of the partition, use following
qm set  592  -scsi2 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F41BLC-part3
```

a very well explained answer related to this could be found at [Proxmox support forum](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/is-it-possible-to-passthrough-a-partition-of-a-drive-to-a-vm-and-not-the-entire-disk.109974/) link.